# Use of Recv-Q and Send-Q

Tags: linux, unix, networking, netstat

What is the use of the Recv-Q and Send-Q columns in netstat's output? How do I use use this in a realistic scenario?

On my system, both of the columns are always shown as zero. What is the meaning for that?

Answer (score 46):

From my man page:

> Recv-Q
>
> Established: The count of bytes not copied by  the  user  program
>   connected to this socket.
>
> Listening: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the current syn
>   backlog.
>
> Send-Q
>
> Established: The count of bytes not acknowledged by  the  remote 
>   host.
>
> Listening: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the maximum size
>   of the syn backlog.

If you have this stuck to 0, this just mean that your applications, on both side of the connection, and the network between them, are doing OK. Actual instant values may be different from 0, but in such a transient, fugitive manner that you don't get a chance to actually observe it.

**Example of real-life scenario where this might be different from 0 (on established connections, but I think you'll get the idea):**

I recently worked on a Linux embedded device talking to a (poorly designed) third party device. On this third party device, the application clearly got stuck sometimes, not reading the data it received on TCP connection, resulting in its TCP window going down to 0 and staying stuck there for tens of seconds (phenomenon observed via wireshark on a mirrored port between the 2 hosts). In such case:

- **Recv-Q:** running `netstat` *on the third party device* (which I had no
  mean to do) may have show an increasing Recv-Q, up to some roof value
  where the other side (me) stop sending data because the window get
  down to 0, since the application does not read the data available on
  its socket, and these data stay buffered in the TCP implementation in
  the OS, not going to the stuck application -> *from the receiver
  side, application issue.*
- **Send-Q:** running `netstat` on *my* side (which I did not tried because
  1/ the problem was clear from wireshark and was the first case above
  and 2/ this was not 100% reproducible) *may* have show a non-zero
  Send-Q, *if* the other side TCP implementation at the OS level have
  been stucked and stopped ACKnowleding my data -> *from the sender
  side, receiving TCP implementation (typically at the OS level) issue.*

Note that the Send-Q scenario depicted above may also be a sending side issue (my side) *if* my Linux TCP implementation was misbehaving and continued to send data after the TCP window went down to 0: the receiving side then has no more room for this data -> does not ACKnowledge.

*Note also that the Send-Q issue may be caused not because of the receiver, but by some routing issue somewhere between the sender and the receiver*. Some packets are "on the fly" between the 2 hosts, but not ACKnowledge yet. *On the other hand, the Recv-Q issue is definitly on a host:* packets received, ACKnowledged, but not read from the application yet.

**EDIT:**

In real life, with non-crappy hosts and applications as you can reasonably expect, *I'd bet the Send-Q issue to be caused most of the time by some routing issue/network poor performances between the sending and receiving side. The "on the fly" state of packets should never be forgotten:*

- The packet may be on the network between the sender and the receiver,
- (or received but ACK not send yet, see above)
- or the ACK may be on the network between the receiver and the sender.

It takes a RTT (round time trip) for a packet to be send and then ACKed.

Comment: Do you happen to know if these are defined the same for the newer `ss` command as for the older `netstat`?  I'm guessing they are, but the man page I have for ss doesn't say what they mean.  The perhaps if they are the same we can update the Q above.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer @jbm.

> Listening: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the current syn
> backlog. Listening: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the
> maximum size of the syn backlog.

they are not syn backlog, they are listen backlog.

Comment: Can you quote where you find it?