# byte in Recv-Q and Send-Q

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

why the amount byte which are in `send-q` and `rec-q` is remains same till the service restart and what would happened for those bytes? explain in detail

```
tcp        0   385870   127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:59039      FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp   416000       0    127.0.0.1:59039        127.0.0.1:3306       ESTABLISHED 34087/java
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of Recv-Q and Send-Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466744/use-of-recv-q-and-send-q)